# Vuejs com VueTable2

Tags: vue.js, vuetable

Estou tentando utilizar o [VueTable-2](https://github.com/ratiw/vuetable-2) enviando as informações via a props `data`. Procurei em diversos sites, testei e nada funcionou, inclusive achei [este exemplo](https://codepen.io/ratiw/pen/LyLpow) no formato que preciso, mas também não funciona. O código mais básico, seria o código abaixo, alguém por acaso sabe o porquê disto não funcionar? Ou a maneira correta.

Coloquei para exibir na tela o objeto de teste que a tabela deveria renderizar.

> Obs.: Com o tipo de `api-mode` igual a `true` funciona perfeitamente, o que preciso, é que funcione com api-mode igual a `false`.

```js
Vue.use(Vuetable);
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    tableColumns: ['id', 'name'],
    itens: [
        { id: 1, name: "Jogos Vorazes" },
        { id: 2, name: "Todo mundo em Pânico" }
    ],
  }
})
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.3.4/vue.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/axios/0.16.2/axios.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vuetable-2@1.6.3"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div id="app" class="container">

  <h1 class="text-center">Vuejs com VueTable-2</h1>

  <hr>

  <vuetable ref="vuetable"
       :api-mode="false"
       :fields="tableColumns"
       :data="itens">
  </vuetable>
  <pre>{{ itens }}</pre>
</div>
```

---

**Editado:**

O projeto VueTable-2 na versão 1.6.3 foi marcado como contendo um bug. O [link da abertura no Git do issue](https://github.com/ratiw/vuetable-2/issues/176). Aguardando a correção para fechar o tópico.

---

**Editado (corrigido):**

> **O bug foi corrigido na versão v1.6.5.**
>   Observação, para quem utilizar a versão 1.6.3 estará com este bug

Comment: Dá-me ideia que esse projeto não está a funcionar bem. Estive a testar e ler a documentação e nada de pôr a funcionar. As tuas props estão consoante a documentação. Parece o mesmo problema que este: https://github.com/ratiw/vuetable-2/issues/176

Comment: @Sergio, o autor do VueTable marcou como Bug. Agora é só aguardar. Obrigado.

Comment: Boa! Pois também me pareceu. Mas há outras vue-table, na volta encontras um projeto mais estável.

Answer (score 0):

> **O bug foi corrigido na versão v1.6.5.**
>   Observação, para quem utilizar a versão 1.6.3 estará com este bug